# How to shift a Project in two Bitbucket account by using an URL?

Tags: android, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I was trying to shift Android code to two different Bitbucket account. but didn't get any success,

```
git remote set-url origin https://Vijay_Singh_Lodhi@bitbucket.org/Vijay_Singh_Lodhi/tipsyride.git
```

Answer (score 1):

Your local git repository may be linked to a few remotes.
To add remote repository run next command
`git remote add {remote name} {remote url}` eg `git remote add personal https://Vijay_Singh_Lodhi@bitbucket.org/Vijay_Singh_Lodhi/tipsyride.git`

`set-url` is a command to change url of existed remote.